# find all the child nodes using the parent nodeid in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

how do i find all the child nodes using the id of a particular parent node in drupal? I tried drual_menu_tree , but it displays only the child of the current page.

Comment: How are you setting the node parent or node children ?

Comment: i think the words primary and secondary best suite the nodes. The primary page is selected from the Parent item: when we create a page from the admin.I want to get the list of secondary pages from the ID of a primary page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no parent-child relation amongst Drupal nodes. From your comment, I suspect you are talking about menus.

If so, have a look at [menu_tree_all_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data). This gives you the links you have in your menu.

1. Deduce the `mlid` (menu link id) of the parent by examining the `link_path`s of the returned items.
2. Find the menu link items that have the found `mlid` as `plid` (parent link id).
3. From those items, filter out the ones that point to a node (by examining their `link_path` again).

This is quite cumbersome to do in PHP. A customized SQL query is probably faster. You would have to query the `{menu_links}` table; it contains the `mlid`, `plid` and `link_path` I was talking about.